# Ruby method to compose Enumerator with function

Tags: ruby, enumerator

If you have an enumerator and some callable (proc/lambda/method) it is sometimes handy to compose them to create a new enumerator, like this

```rb
class Enumerator
  def compose func
    Enumerator.new do |yielder|
      each { |x| yielder << func[x] }
    end
  end
end

# make an enumerator that yields 0, 2, 4, 6...
(0..10).each.compose(proc { |x| x * 2 })
```

Is there no built-in method for doing this? Or no simpler syntax? I've been trawling the docs because we have [Enumerator::+](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-2B) and [Proc::<<](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Proc.html#method-i-3C-3C) which are close but not quite right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sounds like [`Enumerable#map`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)

```
(0..10).each.map { |x| x * 2 }
```

In fact, you don't even need the `each`, since `map` is a method on anything that mixes in `Enumerable`.

```
(0..10).map { |x| x * 2 }
```

If you want to get a lazy enumerator, you can call [`Enumerable#lazy`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-lazy) before applying any transformations. This returns an object on which all of the `Enumerable` methods can be applied lazily.

```
(0..10).lazy.map { |x| x * 2 }
```

Comment: `enum.lazy.map(&:func)` is specifically what I needed since I want to keep it as an enumerator. Thanks!

Comment: @Max `Enumerator::produce` might also be of interest e.g. `enum = Enumerator.produce(0) {|prev| prev + 2}` then `enum.take(10) #=> [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]`